# finding total average list of lists python

Tags: python, average, anova

I am new to python, and I need help with finding averages, variances, and grand average in a list of lists. I have a list of lists like this:

```
allgroups = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

and I am able to find the averages and variances, but for the grand average, I have a problem to find the solution: here is my code:

```
def avg(allgroups):
    return [float(sum(i)) / len(i) for i in allgroups]


def variance(allgroups):
    return [sum((x - sum(group) / len(group)) ** 2 for x in group) / (
                len(group) - 1) for group in allgroups]


def calcavg(allgroups):
    return float(sum(avg(allgroups) / len(avg(allgroups))))

TheAvg = avg(allgroups)
print(TheAvg)
Variance = variance(allgroups)
print(Variance)
calcAvg = calcavg(allgroups)
print(calcAvg)
```

I keep getting the screen error:

```
return float(sum(avg(allgroups) / len(avg(allgroups))))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

When I do the code:

```
average= sum(TheAvg)/len(TheAvg)
```

I could find the grand average, but when I do

```
def calcavg(allgroups):
    return float(sum(avg(allgroups) / len(avg(allgroups))))
```

I keep getting an error. I will be grateful for any help. 
P/S: I can't use any library for this problem such as numpy or statistic.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `calcavg` function. You did not properly inclose the `sum` operator on the left-hand side. The function should be as shown below:

```
def calcavg(allgroups):
    return float(sum(avg(allgroups)) / len(avg(allgroups)))

calcavg(allgroups)

>> 6.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, can I ask you one more question?
I want to count size for every list. How can I do it?
For example: [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6], ...] and the size is [3 , 3 ,3 ]
Thanks

Comment: `[len(group) for group in allgroups]`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I truly appreciate it.